# Django: Static files don't show up in the website despite being referenced correctly

Tags: python, css, django

I've spent the entire day trying to figure out why the static files don't appear on the website despite being referenced correctly. My base template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Sinergia Creativa{% endblock %}</title>
        {% load staticfiles %}
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{%  static 'favicon.ico' %}"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'publicidad/style.css' %}"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topNavBar">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'publicidad:index' %}">Sinergia&nbsp;Creativa</a>
                   </div>
                   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="">
                                <a href="#">Promociones</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="">
                                <a href="#">Contacto</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

My settings.py:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'publicidad.apps.PublicidadConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'sinergia_creativa.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'sinergia_creativa.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I have another project that is configured the same way and that one works so I'm puzzled.

My main problem is that the static files aren't being loaded at all despite actually being referenced and found without issues. I've used findstatic in the manage.py shell and it found them at the correct location. I used Firebug to look at what was being referenced at it was the correct path throwing me this

```
<link href="/static/publicidad/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
Reload the site to obtain the source code of: http://localhost:800/static/publicidad/style.css
```

I don't know what else to do. Other project worked fine under those settings. Let me know if you need any other information from the project.

Cheers, Datkros.

Comment: Why is your Firebug output referencing port 800 instead of 8000?

Comment: Oh, that must've been a mistake on my side or something but it actually references 8000.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see at settings.py define static file. Add more setting into settings.py (in my case static folder is in my project)

```
   import os.path
   # Additional locations of static files
   STATICFILES_DIRS = (
          # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
          # Always use  slashes, even on Windows.
          # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
          # ('static', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')),
          os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
   )
```

Comment: It doesn't work at all. I've tried this before but it still doesn't show up on the website. I even tried using the whole path directly and nothing.